# How can I specify the correct type of bacon in the US?

Tags: bacon, language

I'm in the US, looking for bacon like they have in the UK and (possibly?) Canada. However, if I ask for Canadian Bacon, I receive what is basically a processed ham product that I find far less tasty. How can I specify the cut of meat I'm looking for?

Comment: +1 for calling it "the correct type of bacon" :D Those tiny thin streaky strips of fat you guys call bacon are an abomination to humankind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as "back bacon" in Canada, and when brined rather than smoked, it's peameal bacon. Canadian bacon is, sadly, usually just some sort of processed ham product meant to resemble back bacon. It's also known here in the US as Irish rashers or British rashers (a rasher is the british term for a slice of the sort of bacon you're after). It can also show up as simply Irish bacon or British bacon. Google any of those terms to find internet vendors.

Answer (score 5):

In Canada, we have lots of different types of bacon. I believe in the states, "Canadian" Bacon, as far as I know generally refers to back bacon. Standard Bacon (Also called, side Bacon, Strip Bacon; which comes from the belly), is usually just known as "Bacon". I believe this is true in the states.

What happens when you just ask for "Bacon, please!"?

[Wikipedia link of different cuts of bacon.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacon#Cuts_of_bacon) The link also includes the different local terms for bacon.

Comment: "Bacon", no qualifiers, in the US refers to what they called in the UK "streaky" bacon.

Comment: As for the wikipedia link, it claims "Canadian" bacon should be back bacon, but it's not. Everywhere I've had Canadian Bacon, it's the smoked ham they refer to in the disambig page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_bacon

Comment: Then what are you looking for? You actually looking for the back bacon? In my travels in the states, I can usually get the same thing I find here in Canada. Ask around for "back" bacon maybe?

Comment: Is there an actual butcher near you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm looking to order online or get very very lucky in a supermarket (maybe a high-end one or one that boasts a lot of imports)

Comment: You're looking for something like this? http://www.realcanadianbacon.com/ (Disclaimer: I have no idea the reputation of this place, I just found it via an article about fake Canadian Bacon....)

Comment: No, I want rashers like http://img.thesun.co.uk/multimedia/archive/00722/SNN3118Z_682_722857a.jpg . I was probably misinformed when I was told I could find it in Canada easier

Comment: Canadian Bacon is available only in the US.  It is not available in Canada at all.  What is available in Canada is pickled pork loin, usually rolled in pea meal and sold as Back Bacon or Peameal bacon.  The American Product, called Canadian Bacon is really more of a ham made from the loin.

Comment: Base on your image http://img.thesun.co.uk/multimedia/archive/00722/SNN3118Z_682_722857a.jpg  I think you're looking for shoulder bacon, which is generally not available in North America.

Comment: I've definitely seen that product here in Calgary, but I couldn't tell you where, or what it was labelled as...